# How can I do custom text selection in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, textselection

I just want to do a simple task here. Select some text and then do some manipulation on the selected text.
I have searched for over a day on custom selection in react native but couldn't find any solution for it. Any help would be appreciated.

I tried a package [react-native-selectable-text](https://github.com/Astrocoders/react-native-selectable-text). But GitHub repo for this package is archived and there is a issue in this package. And when I visited the issue list of the repo this issue wasn't entertained and there was not a single comment on that particular issue.

[image]